# Remove duplicates from Arp-Scan Bash output

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need a method to remove the duplicates from this IP list.

```
arp-scan -I usb0 --file=ClassB.txt -N -r 1 --interval=50 | grep -E '([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}' | awk '{print $1}' > IPList.txt
```

Any thoughts or direction I should head in?
I'm needing to get together a list of IP's for another script I have.

THanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort -u` to only print unique lines:

```
arp-scan ...  | awk '/([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}/{print $1}' | sort -u  > IPList.txt
```

As a bonus I've removed your `grep | awk` pipe, as awk is perfectly capable of matching a pattern by itself.

You can even do the whole thing in awk:

```
arp-scan ...  | awk '/([a-f0-9]{2}:){5}[a-f0-9]{2}/&&!seen[$1]++{print $1}' > IPList.txt
```

This only prints the first field when it has not yet been added to the array `seen`, as `!seen[$1]++` will only be true once.

Comment: Thank you! I've marked this as the answer. Is there a way to output the results to screen as the script is running as well as save the results to file?

Comment: @Rob you can pipe the output to `tee` to do that